# with open my_file.yml doesnt properly load my file

Tags: python

Im running a digitalocean droplet and i need to provide a json with the content of a yml in the "user_data" entry like this :

```
with open("cloud-config.yml", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    data = {"name": f"{server_name}",
        "region":"ams3",
        "size":"s-1vcpu-1gb",
        "image": "debian-11-x64 ",
        "ssh_keys": [list_key()[0],#
        list_key()[1]],
        "backups": True,
        "ipv6": True,
        "monitoring": True,
        "user_data": """content of yml""",
        "with_droplet_agent":True,
    }
```

the content of yml is :

```
   #cloud-config
    users:
      - name: username
        ssh-authorized-keys:
          - sshkey
        sudo: ['ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL']
        groups: sudo
        shell: /bin/bash
    runcmd:
      - sed -i -e '/^PermitRootLogin/s/^.*$/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      - sed -i -e '$aAllowUsers username' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      - restart ssh
      - sudo apt -y update
      - sudo apt install -y nano
      - sudo apt install -y rsync
      - sudo apt install -y ufw
      - sudo apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common
      - sudo curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
      - sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
      - sudo apt -y update
      - sudo apt-cache policy docker-ce
      - sudo apt install -y docker-ce
      - sudo apt install -y docker-compose
      - sudo groupadd docker
      - sudo usermod -aG docker kr1p
      - newgrp docker
      - sudo setfacl --modify user:kr1p:rw /var/run/docker.sock
      - sudo systemctl start docker
      - sudo systemctl enable docker.service
      - sudo systemctl enable containerd.service
      - sudo fallocate -l 2G /swapfile
      - sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
      - sudo mkswap /swapfile
      - sudo swapon /swapfile
      - sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
      - echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
      - sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=50
      - echo 'vm.swappiness=50' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
      - sudo sysctl vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
      - echo 'vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 50' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
      - sudo mkdir /root/.ssh
      - sudo touch '/root/.ssh/authorized_keys'
      - sudo systemctl restart sshd
      - sudo ufw default deny incoming
      - sudo ufw default allow outgoing
      - sudo ufw allow ssh
      - sudo ufw allow 22
      - sudo ufw allow 80
      - sudo ufw allow 443
      - sudo ufw allow 4000
      - sudo ufw allow 4001
      - sudo ufw allow 4002
      - sudo ufw allow 4003
      - sudo ufw allow 4004
      - sudo ufw allow 4005
      - sudo ufw allow 4006
      - sudo ufw allow 4007
      - sudo ufw allow 4008
      - sudo ufw allow 4009
      - sudo ufw allow 4010
      - echo 'y' | sudo ufw enable
```

If i copy paste the content of my yml inside triple quotes in my .py script it works. But if I replace the user_data line with

```
    "user_data": f"{cloudconfig.read()}"
```

or

```
"user_data": f"""{cloudconfig.read()}"""
```

Then it doesnt work.
How come this happens? Is it related to the parsing of \n and whitespaces? How can i make it work?

Comment: You have a typo in your code after reading file  in this line `"user_data": f"""{cloudconfig.read()}"""`

Comment: no there's no typo

Comment: Try `user_data = f"{cloudconfig.read()}"`. F-string format already return a string, you don't need to double quote again

Comment: Please post the working code, when reading YAML as string. So we can compare and reproduce (we don't have a file). Agree with @ShivaGaire that the last line is rather YAML-syntax than valid Python-code.

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to put `with` statement in the middle of `data` dict literal definition.  I wouldn't expect that to work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) to work with `yaml` file in python.

First, install it using `pip`

```
pip install pyyaml
```

Then you can load your `yaml` file

```
import yaml
with open("cloud-config.yml", mode="rt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    config = yaml.safe_load(file)
    print(config)
```

From what I have understood if you need content of YAML and in your data dictionary

Try doing this:

```
data = {"name": f"{server_name}",
        "region":"ams3",
        "size":"s-1vcpu-1gb",
        "image": "debian-11-x64 ",
        "ssh_keys": [list_key()[0],#
        list_key()[1]],
        "backups": True,
        "ipv6": True,
        "user_data": "content of yml",
        "monitoring": True,
        "with_droplet_agent":True,
    }

with open("cloud-config.yml", mode="rt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    config = yaml.safe_load(file)
    data.update(user_data=yaml.dump(config))
```

Comment: this doesnt work at all..it's only helpful to load yml in a structured way . my problem is it's working when i copy paste the yml as a string but not when i load the string from a file.

Comment: Do you need `user_data` value  in json in YAML format?

Comment: This is a wrong answer, OP never said they needed a parsed YAML.

Answer (score -1):

```
import json

# what you didn't present us
server_name = 'stackoverflow.com'
list_key = lambda: ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']

# merging in your YAML input
def from_file(path):
    with open(path,'r') as f:
        return f.read()

# your given JSON
data = {"name": server_name,  # no f-string needed
        "region":"ams3",
        "size":"s-1vcpu-1gb",
        "image": "debian-11-x64 ",
        "ssh_keys": list_key()[:2],  # use slicing to get list of first 2
        "backups": True,
        "ipv6": True,
        "monitoring": True,
        "user_data": from_file('cloud-config.yaml'),  # should replace this value with YAML read from file
        "with_droplet_agent":True,
}


# print merged JSON
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Suppose your `cloud-config.yaml` contains:

```
hello: world
list:
    - bananas
    - milk: {free_of: ["lactose", "fat"]}
amount: 4.2
```

Then the code prints following JSON (with YAML content as escaped string):

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflwo.com",
  "region": "ams3",
  "size": "s-1vcpu-1gb",
  "image": "debian-11-x64 ",
  "ssh_keys": [
    "key1",
    "key2"
  ],
  "backups": true,
  "ipv6": true,
  "monitoring": true,
  "user_data": "hello: world\nlist:\n    - bananas\n    - milk: {free_of: [\"lactose\", \"fat\"]}\namount: 4.2\n",
  "with_droplet_agent": true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, it does work for me if I fix variable name to match:

```py
# note `as cloudcofig` instead of `as file`
with open("cloud-config.yml", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as cloudconfig:
    data = {
        "user_data": f"{cloudconfig.read()}"
    }
print(len(data["user_data"]))
```

```
2335
```